# sql function last() is not a recognized function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, exception

I am trying to use the Last() function on my sql server 2008 DB in order to pull out the last record on the table.
to be more specific, the query I'm using is:

```
select Last(Id_Number) as id from table1
```

the exception I get starts this way and continue long after.. but the point is at the first line:

http://prntscr.com/1d4o6y

what can I do?

Comment: What's wrong with `select max(id_number) as id from table1`

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server` doesn't support `LAST`.  You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `@@Identity` or `IDENT_CURRENT(‘table1`’)`.  For example:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table1') AS Id
```

Or if you're not using an `IDENTITY` column and insert the ID's manually.  You can use `MAX`.

```
SELECT MAX(Id_Number) AS Id
FROM Table1
```

Comment: [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) is preferred over `@@IDENTITY`. `@@IDENTITY` will pick up values from triggers; `SCOPE_IDENTITY` only shows changes from what you did, which is almost certainly what you want.

Comment: SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table1') AS Id

Comment: @Joe - added SCOPE_IDENTITY to the answer.

Comment: And both `MAX(Id_Number)` and `IDENT_CURRENT('table1')` will have race conditions -- they won't necessarily pick up the change *you* just made; they'll pick up the latest change *anyone* made. If multiple updates are happening quickly, you could pick up the ID someone else inserted after you, not your own.

Comment: @Joe - you are assuming that they want the last id they inserted when the OP states the last record in the table....

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last record *and* you have an identity column (or a column where the largest value would represent the last record):

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
order by id desc;
```