# Last value selection in SQL-Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to select last values of the columns in the datatable from the SQL Server Database.

My code is

```
private void bind_chart()
        {
            // here i am using SqlDataAdapter for the sql server select query
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select last() * from Test", con);
            // here am taking datatable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                // here datatale dt is fill wit the adp
                adp.Fill(dt);
                // this string m catching in the stringbuilder class
                // in the str m writing same javascript code that is given by the google.
                // my data that will come from the sql server
                // below code is same like as google's javascript code
                str.Append(@" <script type='text/javascript'>
                        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                        function drawChart() {
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');");
                // inside the below line dt.Rows.Count explain that
                // how many rows comes in dt or total rows
                str.Append("data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");

                Int32 i;
                for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    // i need this type of output "  data.setValue(0, 0, 'Memory'); so on  in the first line so for this
                    //m using i for the 0,1& 2 and so on . and after this i am writting zero and after this student_name using datatable
                    str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["x"].ToString() + "');");
                    // i need this type of output "   data.setValue(0, 1, 80);
                    //so on  in the first line so for this
                    //m using i for the 0,1& 2 and so on . and after this i am writting zero and after this percentage using datatable
                    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["y"].ToString() + ") ;");
                    //   str.Append("['" + (dt.Rows[i]["student_name"].ToString()) + "'," + dt.Rows[i]["average_marks"].ToString() + "],");
                }

                str.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                // in the below line i am setting the height and width of the Gauge using your own requrirement
                str.Append(" var options = {width: 800, height: 300, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,");
                //  str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                str.Append("yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5};");
                str.Append("chart.draw(data, options);}");
                str.Append("</script>");
                lt.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

And want to display the last value on the gauge.
Here I am not getting the last value from the query I generated. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and recommended method.

```
select top 1 * from test order by ID desc
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think *Last()* is not a function of sql-server

But you can get the last row by using my below way's .Try this

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE PrimaryKeyId= (SELECT MAX(PrimaryKeyId) FROM TableName )
```

or , try another way.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName ORDER BY PrimaryKeyId DESC
```

> make sure set identity for your primary key .

Comment: I am trying something from this example http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_last&ss=-1

Comment: Okay Leave that way, Now you try my two way's, It's surely get the last row values .]

Comment: Working..thnx @ Ramesh

Comment: Okay : see this thread for : [sql function last() is not a recognized function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425762/sql-function-last-is-not-a-recognized-function)

Comment: Actually I am moving the stylus of the gauge dynamically on the basis of the last value updated in the database. And it is quite use full the thread you gave.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server doesn't support LAST() syntax. Instead you can use another approach described here - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp

Comment: I dont want specific column, I want every column's last value

Comment: You can still do all column ( select * ). Also, the code needs to define what it means to be "LAST". If you are interested in the row that was inserted last, you will need to maintain "LastUpdated" column and order by that in the select query. SQL server does not guarentee how the rows are selected, unless the query specifies ORDER BY.